# Drop Marker with 3857 projection in leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible in leaflet to drop marker with 3857 projection on map?

I found a solution where i first translate a point to 4326 using proj4js and than drop it on a map.

```
var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3857');
    var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');
    var p = new Proj4js.Point(-12307.601047734, 6711475.1283642);
    Proj4js.transform(source, dest, p);
```

new L.Marker([p.y, p.x], {bounceOnAdd: true}).addTo(map);

Is there any other way in core leaflet or leaflet plugin to drop marker without using proj4js library?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Proj4 Leaflet plugin (built on top of Proj4js) that you could try - 
https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet

Although the author of that plugin [has stated](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/leaflet-proj4leaflet-with-multiple-projections) that it is not possible to have multiple projections on the same leaflet map - suggesting you might want your entire leaflet map (and all markers/layers) to be in 3857...