# Use Lambert 93 imageOverlay with Leaflet on top of OSM tiles layer

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, leaflet, gdalwarp, proj4js

I'm trying to use a Lambert 93 image overlay on top of an Open Street Map title layer.

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { }).addTo(map);
var coords = {
    x : [-0.734794,-0.418381],
    y : [47.376276,47.572680]
};
var imageBounds = [[coords.y[0], coords.x[0]], [coords.y[1], coords.x[1]]];
L.imageOverlay('image.png', imageBounds, {opacity:0.8}).addTo(map);
```

The resulting image overlay does not match the underlying OSM map.

[image]

[image: OSM and lambert mismatch]

It seems that this is because the `image.png` is in *lambert 93* projection.

- Can I use a lambert 93 image overlay on top of an OSM tiles layer ?
- If not possible, can I convert my lambert 93 `image.png` to be usable with OSM tiles layers using tools such as `gdalwrap` ?

**What I tried :**

1) Proj4Leaflet

I looked at the [Proj4Leaflet](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) project which enables projections and provides an [imageOverlay with projection example](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/tree/master/examples/imageoverlay) but the projection systems seems to concern the whole map and I want lambert 93 only on the imageOverlay.

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/leaflet-proj4leaflet-with-multiple-projections) seems to exclude the possibility of multiple projections 
but as it only focuses on tiles layers I'm not sure this is relevant in my case.

2) gdalwrap

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:2154 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -of PNG image-lambert.png image-webmercator.png
```

=> Output driver `PNG' not recognised or does not support

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:2154 -t_srs EPSG:3857 image-lambert.png image-webmercator.tiff
```

Copying color table from image-lambert.png to new file.
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line
and georeferenced coordinates for image-lambert.png.
There is no affine transformation and no GCPs.

Comment: That looks a lot larger than RGF93 - WGS84 offset which should at most a meter or so. Are you sure the data's not based on NTF?

Comment: Yes, it's EPSG:2154 which according to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/rgf93-lambert-93/ seems to be lambert 93

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a lambert 93 image overlay on top of an OSM tiles layer ?

Leaflet is **not** able to reproject images. In other words: you can **not** display tiles/images which use different spatial reference systems.

> If not possible, can I convert my lambert 93 image.png to be usable with OSM tiles layers using tools such as gdalwrap ?

Sure! Just remember the EPSG codes for Lambert 93 and OSM's web mercator:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:2154 -t_srs EPSG:3857 image-lambert.png image-webmercator.png
```

Comment: `gdalwrap` seem to be missing some geospatial data to compute transformation (see edited post). Can I add those in `gdalwrap` parameters ?